# Build Parent Child Array using File Path StringArray

Tags: java

I have a list of file paths as String Array or List of Strings

```
Example,
  /A/B/C/D/1.txt
  /A/E/F/D
  /B/F/F/D
  /A/B/C/D/R/3.txt
```

I need to build a a json structure as hierarchy or parent child array so that i can build the json structure

```
 Example,
   A: [
     children:[
    {
       reference:"B": [
          children:[ 
             reference:"C"
          ]
       ]
    }     
   ]
   ........
```

Please help me with your suggestions

Comment: I would suggest that you learn about JSON libraries such as gson and jackson, and then use one to serialize an appropriate domain object.

Comment: How to define the model or how to build the hierarchy using the file path column?

Comment: Plain String operations should do. Look into String#split in the javadocs. From there, you can iterate over the result and build up your JSON using the libraries azurefrog suggested.

Comment: mkzh, could you please help me with a code snippet or suedo code?

Comment: @Kathir I suggest you read [How to Ask a Good Question](/help/how-to-ask) and then post an [mcve]